# Dependency Scope Issues with MediatR and SimpleInjector

Tags: c#, entity-framework, simple-injector, mediator, mediatr

I've been experimenting with the mediator pattern and CQRS using the [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR) library in a WinForms application that uses the Entity Framework for data access. The application is used in a batch manufacturing plant, and allows users to see a list of active and completed batches, and if necessary make updates to batch information. Each batch has a large amount of information associated with it, such as quality and process measurements. Reading and writing data is organized into Queries and Commands, based on these articles:

[Meanwhile... on the query side of my architecture](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92)

[CQRS with MediatR and AutoMapper](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/05/05/cqrs-with-mediatr-and-automapper/)

Here is a simple example of a query and query handler. `DataContext` is injected into the query handler using SimpleInjector.

```
public class GetAllBatchesQuery: IRequest<IEnumerable<Batch>> { }

public class GetAllBatchesQueryHandler :
    IRequestHandler<GetAllBatchesQuery, IEnumerable<Batch>>
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public GetAllBatchesQueryHandler(DataContext context)
    {
        _context= context;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Batch> Handle(GetAllBatchesQueryrequest)
    {
        return _db.Batches.ToList();
    }
}
```

This would be called from the presenter as follows:

```
var batches = mediator.Send(new GetAllBatchesQuery());
```

The problem that I'm running into is with the lifetime of the DbContext. Ideally, I'd like to use a single instance per isolated transaction, which in this case would include such things as:

- Retrieving the list of batches from the database
- Retrieving a list of quality metrics for a batch (these are stored in a different database and accessed through a stored procedure)
- Updating a batch, which may include updating multiple entities in the database

This would lead me towards a scoped or transient lifestyle for DbContext. However, when using a transient lifestyle, SimpleInjector raises the following error, which is thrown when registering the type as follows:

```
container.Register<DataContext>();
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'SimpleInjector.DiagnosticVerificationException' occurred in SimpleInjector.dll
>
> Additional information: The configuration is invalid. The following diagnostic warnings were reported:
>
> -[Disposable Transient Component] DataContext is registered as transient, but implements IDisposable.

Researching this issue on the SimpleInjector website reveals the following [note](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetimes.html#transient):

> Warning: Transient instances are not tracked by the container. This means that Simple Injector will not dispose transient instances.

This led me down the path of using a Lifetime Scope lifestyle for the DataContext. To achieve this, I created a new decorator class for my queries and registered it as follows:

```
public class LifetimeScopeDecorator<TRequest, TResponse> :
    IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> _decorated;
    private readonly Container _container;

    public LifetimeScopeDecorator(
        IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> decorated,
        Container container)
    {
        _decorated = decorated;
        _container = container;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest message)
    {
        using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var result = _decorated.Handle(message);
            return result;
        }
    }
}

...

container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
    typeof(ExecutionContextScopeDecorator<,>));
```

However, making that change causes a different exception, this time thrown at the following line:

```
var batches = mediator.Send(new GetAllBatchesQuery());
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in MediatR.dll
>
> Additional information: Handler was not found for request of type MediatorTest.GetAllBatchesQuery.
>
> Container or service locator not configured properly or handlers not registered with your container.

After debugging and looking through the MediatR code, it appears that when the `mediator.Send(...)` method is called, a new instance of the `GetAllBatchesQueryHandler` class is created by calling `container.GetInstance()`. However, since `DataContext` is not within an execution scope at this point, it may not be properly initialized, causing the exception.

I believe I understand the root cause of the issue, but am at a loss as to how to effectively resolve it. To help illustrate this problem better, I developed the following minimal example. Any class that implements `IDisposable` will result in the same issue that I am having with `DataContext`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using MediatR;
using SimpleInjector;
using SimpleInjector.Extensions.LifetimeScoping;

namespace MediatorTest
{
    public class GetRandomQuery : IRequest<int>
    {
        public int Min { get; set; }
        public int Max { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetRandomQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetRandomQuery, int>
    {
        private readonly RandomNumberGenerator _r;

        public GetRandomQueryHandler(RandomNumberGenerator r)
        {
            _r = r;
        }

        public int Handle(GetRandomQuery request)
        {
            return _r.Next(request.Min, request.Max);
        }
    }

    public class RandomNumberGenerator : IDisposable
    {
        private Random _random = new Random();

        public RandomNumberGenerator() { }

        public void Dispose() { }

        public int Next(int min, int max)
        {
            var result = _random.Next(min, max);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public class LifetimeScopeDecorator<TRequest, TResponse> :
        IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
        where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
    {
        private readonly IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> _decorated;
        private readonly Container _container;

        public LifetimeScopeDecorator(
            IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse> decorated,
            Container container)
        {
            _decorated = decorated;
            _container = container;
        }

        public TResponse Handle(TRequest message)
        {
            using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope())
            {
                var result = _decorated.Handle(message);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var assemblies = GetAssemblies();

            var container = new Container();
            container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new LifetimeScopeLifestyle();
            container.RegisterSingleton<IMediator, Mediator>();
            container.Register<RandomNumberGenerator>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
            container.Register(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), assemblies);
            container.RegisterSingleton(new SingleInstanceFactory(container.GetInstance));
            container.RegisterSingleton(new MultiInstanceFactory(container.GetAllInstances));
            container.RegisterDecorator(
                typeof(IRequestHandler<,>),
                typeof(LifetimeScopeDecorator<,>));

            container.Verify();

            var mediator = container.GetInstance<IMediator>();

            var value = mediator.Send(new GetRandomQuery() { Min = 1, Max = 100 });

            Console.WriteLine("Value = " + value);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static IEnumerable<Assembly> GetAssemblies()
        {
            yield return typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            yield return typeof(GetRandomQuery).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your decoratee (with its `DbContext` dependency) is created at the time the decorator is created, and at that time there is no active scope (since you create it at a later point in time). You should use a decoratee factory as decribed [here](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#decorators-with-func-t-decoratee-factories). In other words, your `LifetimeScopeDecorator` should be implemented as follows:

```
public class LifetimeScopeDecorator<TRequest, TResponse> :
    IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : IRequest<TResponse>
{
    private readonly Func<IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>> _decorateeFactory;
    private readonly Container _container;

    public LifetimeScopeDecorator(
        Func<IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>> decorateeFactory,
        Container container)
    {
        _decorateeFactory = decorateeFactory;
        _container = container;
    }

    public TResponse Handle(TRequest message)
    {
        using (_container.BeginLifetimeScope())
        {
            var result = _decorateeFactory.Invoke().Handle(message);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The difference with your original implementation is that a `Func<IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>>` is injected instead of an `IRequestHandler<TRequest, TResponse>`. This allows Simple Injector to postpone the creation after the scope has been created.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you!